# Перемножение вторых элементов кортежа

Tags: haskell, функциональное-программирование

Мною была реализована функция multSecond, которая перемножает вторые элементы пар:

```
import Data.Function

multSecond :: Num c => (a, c) -> (a, c) -> c
multSecond = g `on` h

g :: Num a1 => (a2, a1) -> (a3, a1) -> a1
g (_,y) (_,z) = (y * z)

h :: a -> a
h = id
```

Данный код работает локально, но проверочная система stepik выдает следующую ошибку:

```
Compilation error

main.hs:20:6:
   No instance for (Num a0) arising from a use of ‘g’
   The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
   Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance Num Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
  instance Num Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
  instance Integral a => Num (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
    -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
  ...plus three others
 In the first argument of ‘(==)’, namely ‘g 2 7’
 In the expression: g 2 7 == 14
 In the expression:
  [multSecond ('A', 2) ('E', 7) == 14,
   multSecond (True, 3) (False, 4) == 12,
   multSecond (undefined, 9) ("Hello", 9) == 81,
   multSecond (undefined, 44) (undefined, 1) == 44, ....]

main.hs:20:8:
  No instance for (Num (a1, a0)) arising from the literal ‘2’
  In the first argument of ‘g’, namely ‘2’
  In the first argument of ‘(==)’, namely ‘g 2 7’
  In the expression: g 2 7 == 14
  ........
```

Вопрос: В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Судя по тексту ошибки, вы почему-то пытаетесь выполнить код `g 2 7 == 14`, что разумеется не работает, потому что `2` и `7` - не кортежи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по сообщению, проверяющая система ожидает от `g` такого поведения

```
g 2 7 == 14
```

И хоть формально ваше решение соответствует заданию, ожидается что `g` должна принимать числа, а не пары. Так что придется переложить работу с парой на `h`.